# Unit testing of communication-classes

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have a class used for handling a connection to an external system.
The class has some a few public methods, let's say:

- close()
- configure()
- send()
- connect()

And a handful of private methods.
The class is intended to hide most of the re-establishing, fail-checking and connection-handling in the internal works.

Now, I get a code coverage error on this, since there is no unit tests for this class, besides the configure-method.

- Is there another way of writing unit tests for such classes, except for heavy mocking?
- If so, isn't that a good proof the class should be tested at an intergration-test or system-test level rather than unit-test? Do communication-classes belong to unit-tests or system tests?

Comment: I agree with your second point. IMHO, such classes are not suitable for unit testing and are candidates for exceptions in unit test coverage. You could mock everything, of course, but then the unit test would be worthless as it is only testing your mock functionality.

Comment: I think you have to mock, because if it connected your code is partial used, you will have to disconnect and reconnect you computer to go in your code, it's not easy. If there is no network "failure" a little part of your code will be tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you cannot instantiate the external system locally in an unit test, this task is a classical integration or system test. So the communication classes, typically do not belong to unit tests.
The coverage will be low for such classes, showing that there is
need to test them otherwise.

Further the coverage report, e.g in SonarCube can (hopefully) be filtered.
One could define exception filters, together with the responsible person (e.g Software Architect.)
It may help to move all such communication classes to its own package.
Or even to its own project or jar file. For that project the coverage would then not be executed.

Sometimes it makes sense to build a dummy external system, to work with.
If the external system is yet under development and when it changes its interfaces daily, you can lose much time in using the external system.
In such situations a dummy system can be used, which is maybe instantiable from the unit test, too.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the amount of code in the class. If it just configures another service (like a socket or a database driver), unit testing doesn't make sense since someone probably already tested the actual service.

If the code is very complex (error handling, data transformation), you should write unit tests for this part of the code and mock the service out.